# Usage of "__call__(self,x): return self.foo_method(x)" and its difference to "class.foo_method(x)"

Tags: python, class, methods, neural-network, class-method

The code derives from a neural network implementation from scratch in python, you can check full code on this  [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-evolution-strategy-1b78b9d48385)  if you want and down here the critical part concerning my question which is I hope python oriented:

```
class model:
   def __init__(self,blah blah...):
      blah blah

   def forward(self,x):
      blah blah
      return output_of_neural_network

   def __call__(self,x):
      return forward(x)
```

Presuming that we want to use the forward method in the following part of our code...

What is the purpose of calling the class as a function e.g. `model(xtrain)` instead of `model.forward(xtrain)`?

Are there any functional differences associated with the instance or the variables of the class object when being called as a function instead of applying its method directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, as you thought, pure syntactic sugar with no functional difference at all.

I guess the reasoning behind this is thinking of your `Model` as transforming the input data. This, I believe, `scikit-learn` chooses to do with its `transform` method, which is arguably less ambiguous.